# How can I concatenate two "videoCategoryId" in the same query for a video?

Tags: api, youtube

I'm using a query to get youtube video by id, using the youtube api v3,
when i use the paramenter

```
    &videoCategoryId=10
```

it works fine, but what if I want to filter all videos belonging to either one or another category?
i tried with:

```
    &videoCategoryId=10,24
```

but doesn't work.

any expert of youtube api? the documentation doesn't explain this.

Comment: Have you checked whether a video has more than two `videoCategories`? if so, please , [edit] you question and add it.

Comment: Off topic, youtube api can obviously search for multiple videos, so my question is clearly "can I retrieve only videos from EITHER category 10 OR category 24?" not "can i retrieve videos belongings to two categories at once".

Comment: Nathan ,I don't see the off-topic, though. you can also made two request *(each request with a `videoCategoryId`)* - Curious enough, if you test this [request](https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#p/youtube/v3/youtube.videos.list?part=snippet&chart=mostPopular&maxResults=4&videoCategoryId=24&fields=eventId%252Citems(contentDetails(dimension%252Cduration)%252Cid%252Ckind%252Csnippet(categoryId%252CchannelId%252CchannelTitle%252Cdescription%252Ctitle))%252Ckind%252CnextPageToken%252CpageInfo%252CprevPageToken%252CtokenPagination&_h=4&) you'll get results from videoCategories 23,17 and 1

Answer (score 0):

Since the [documentation says](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/search/list?hl=en):

> **`videoCategoryId`** **`string`**:
>
> The **`videoCategoryId`** parameter filters video search results based
>   on their category. *If you specify **a value** for this parameter*, you must
>   also set the type parameter's value to video.

**It is not possible add more than one `videoCategoryId` at the same time.**

You have to make that each request has different `videoCategoryId`.

Comment: Can't see a correlation with what you posted and what I asked. What they state there with "their category" could even be multiple parameters for what we know, it's not specified.

Comment: @NathanBernard , the answer is that you can't concatenate two `videoCategoryId` in the same request.

Comment: Because you said so? There are tons of stuff out of the documentation that actually work, both with Youtube API and Firebase, to name two of them.

Comment: @NathanBernard no, the documentation AND my testings says so. Now you mentioned, you can use Firebase. Check this [demo](https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#p/youtube/v3/youtube.search.list?part=snippet&maxResults=30&order=videoCount&regionCode=US&topicId=%252Fm%252F02vxn%252C%252Fm%252F02jjt&type=video&videoCategoryId=10&fields=items(id%252FvideoId%252Ckind%252Csnippet(channelId%252CchannelTitle%252Ctitle))%252CnextPageToken%252CpageInfo%252CprevPageToken%252CregionCode%252CtokenPagination&_h=9&).